# Laravel SSL .htaccess redirection to index.php

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with redirection in my laravel 5 app. I configure `.htaccess` to work with SSL - it's working good. The problem is when I type:

`example.com/page` - should show `page` route but browser redirect to `https://example.com/index.php`

When I type full address into browser like `https://example.com/page` route working good eg. in browser I see my `page` route (blade, itp).
What's the problem?

My `.htaacess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    order deny,allow
    deny from all

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the "Handle authorization header" **BEFORE** the "Handle Front Controller"

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Otherwise, the main front controller transformation won't be reached if there is an http to https redirection.

Answer (score 0):

As @Amarnasan has mentioned, but if it still doesn't work, delete your browser's cache after that it should work.